# Modify TCP/IP protocol on router

Tags: router, tcp

I want to conduct an experiment under which i need to add some functionality to IP protocol in intermediate routers of my setup.
Are there routers in market with which i could modify IP protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index

This is an open-source firmware that is suitable for a large number of devices, as it being opensource i think you can achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any router that supports [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index), which will give you a great starting point!

Comment: I want to compile modified tcp/ip protocol, not able to find any related info from DD-WRT website

Comment: This is the joy of open source :) Trace through the code and learn the places you could modify it.